# How to create a ListView with data in a List<objet> - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, list, listview, kotlin

I've started to learn mobile app development with Java and Kotlin (using Android Studio) and I'm stuck with something:
Ihave a kotlin class in a file, this is the code:

```
data class Clients (
val Id: Long,
val name: String,
val phoneNumber: List<String>,
val avatar: Uri?
);
```

and I have this code in the MainActivity(Java):

```
List<Clients> infos = InfosKt.retrieveAll(getApplicationContext());
```

My ListView code in my MainActivity:

```
ListView list_clients;
list_clients = findViewById(R.id.list_allclients);
```

I just want to know, How Can I put the data from List in a ListView ? The idea is that users see the Name and Phone numbers of all Clients.

Is there a way to convert the List in an Array ?

Comment: You should try [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) instead which is a more advanced and flexible version of `ListView`

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi Ok, Thanks, I'll read about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the actual items in the list - you do with with an `Adapter`, where you actually create a `View` and put the data in it.

There's an [example on the Android developer site](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/ListView) (not in Kotlin for some reason but you'll get the idea):

```
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
 
       // override other abstract methods here
 
       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
           if (convertView == null) {
               convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, container, false);
           }
 
           ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1))
                   .setText(getItem(position));
           return convertView;
       }
   }
```

What's basically happening is whenever the `ListView` needs to create an entry, it calls `getView` in the adapter. That inflates a list item layout, which you need to create - `TextViews` for your name and phone number, an `ImageView` for your avatar, that kind of thing.

Then you just find those views and fill them with your data - `getItem` is passing in a `position` value for the item's position in the list, so you use that to grab the right data object out of your array, and then you can set up your views to display it.

So you write that class, then call `setAdapter(MyAdapter())` and the `ListView` will use it.

Someone recommended `RecyclerView`s instead, they are more efficient and the way you're supposed to do things, but they're also way more complicated. So I think this is the best way to learn the basic idea of making a layout, inflating it and filling it with data. Once you understand that, all the RecyclerView boilerplate will be a little easier to handle!